# Ansible Jinja2 for loop variable loses scope in 'lookup'

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Within a jinja2 template, I am iterating again over an already looped dictionary value which is set using dict2items via an ansible task.  That is working as expected.  Calling that variable within the jinja2 'for' loop works except for when referenced in a file lookup.  Is this expected behavior and if so, how else could I make this work?

```
{% for filename in item.value.filenames %}
{{ item.value.filenames[filename] }} #works

{{ filename }} #works

{{ lookup('file', '/somedir/{{ item.value.filenames[filename] }}') }} #does not work, variable filename undefined

{{ lookup('file', '/somedir/{{ filename }}') }} #does not work, variable filename undefined

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names) => `{{ lookup('file', '/somedir/' ~ item.value.filenames[filename]) }}` or `{{ lookup('file', '/somedir/' ~ filename) }}` (whatever is the good value in your situation)